# Does anyone know how to implement Speech/Voice to Text for a Windows Phone 7.1 Application?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7.1, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I have tried searching all over the internet and it seems, it is not available,.I'll appreciate your help even if you can provide me a code sample for a web based V to T conversion.Even the Phonegap way is also appreciated
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved voice to text using the Dragon SDK a third party library and for the text to speech used a web service where we process the texts using the SAPI